# Set the name of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary of unknown size, with keys=integers and value=strings.
I need to create a dictionary for every entry. Moreover I need the values of the previous dictionary to be the names of the new dictionaries.

Example:

```
dict1 = {0:'One', 1:'Two', 2:'Three'}
for key,value in dict1.items():
    value = {}
```

in this way of course I get the number of dictionaries I want but not the name. I wish I had:

```
One = {}
Two = {}
Three = {}
```

Comment: You really don't want this; [keep your data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). Use a dictionary to store `'One'`, `'Two'` and `'Three'` as keys instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I need to use One, Two, Three as dictionaries in the rest of the script. I can save them as keys instead of values in the fist dictionary but what's the difference to reach my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. You can use dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary with the value as the key and the new value as an empty dictionary, like this.

```
dict1= {0:'One', 1:'Two', 2:'Three'}
print {value:{} for key,value in dict1.items()}
```

**Output**

```
{'Three': {}, 'Two': {}, 'One': {}}
```

Dictionary cannot maintain order. Thats `One`, `Two` and `Three` out of order. If you wan to access the individual dictionaries, you can do like this

```
d = {value:{} for key,value in dict1.items()}
d['Three']['a'] = 1
```

Comment: thanks! but then when I write Three['a'] = 'b' it raise an NameError: Three not defined.

Comment: @JAWE, are you trying to create local variable with those names? That's generally a bad idea.

Comment: @JAWE Please check my answer now. We can access them with a dictionary of dictionary.

Comment: @gnibbler what would you suggest me to do? I need to create a unknown number of dictionaries with the names are are the value of another dictionary.

Comment: @thefourtheye sorry maybe I was not clear but I need One, Two Three to be the name of the dictionaries.

Comment: @JAWE You mean, you need to define local variables with those names? If yes, thats usually a bad idea.

Comment: @JAWE, you have it the wrong way round. They would be the _keys_ of the dict

Comment: @thefourtheye ok so what should I do? If I'm asking is because I don't know how to do :)

Comment: @JAWE No worries. You can access the dictionaries like this `d['Three']['a'] = 1`. As you spend more time with python, you ll understand and love this way of accessing things :)

Answer (score 1):

```
names = 'One', 'Two', 'Three'
my_dict = {k: {} for k in names}
```

now you have these "variables"

```
my_dict['One']
my_dict['Two']
my_dict['Three']
```

Nicely grouped together inside my_dict without polluting your namespace. You can loop over them or call them by name etc.